# Post request in iframe with same domain

Tags: javascript, post, iframe

I have an Iframe loaded inside my page. Both my page and iframe have same domain. I have some javascript inside my iframe that makes an ajax POST request to a url in same domain. But request is not reaching my server. All I see is '403 Forbidden' when I logged the xhr object on the console. GET requests are working fine. Need help with this.

I'm using chrome.

Comment: 403 is a server response. You would be getting a javascript error if this was a cross domain issue.

Comment: But request is not reaching server at all. None of post requests are working. when I tried firing the same request from outside the iframe it works.

Comment: If the request was not reaching the server at all, where would the 403 response code come from?

Comment: It is showing in xhr object and on Network tab on chrome.